# Yarn upgrade-interactive always to `exotic`

Tags: upgrade, package.json, yarnpkg

I'm playing around with a centralized build setup which is hosted on github: https://github.com/skybrud/sky-build-setup/tree/master

In the npm module this repo is used, I have the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sky-crop",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "description": "Vue component for cropping images",
  "main": "dist/skycrop.js",
  "scripts": {
    "vanilla": "rimraf ./node_modules && yarn run dist",
    "build": "rimraf ./dist && webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "dist": "yarn install && yarn run build"
  },
  "build": "module",
  "author": "Skybrud.dk",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/skybrud/sky-crop.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sky-window": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sky-build-setup": "https://github.com/skybrud/sky-build-setup.git#semver:^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my issue. When running `yarn upgrade-interactive` I always get the following:
[image]

For some reason the `to` part always refers to `exotic` in stead of being up to date.

Can someone point me in the right direction about what is going on?
And what does `exotic` exactly mean? I haven't been able to locate the description anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yarn can't manage dependencies versions for dependencies not belonging to the npm packages repository.

In your case, the devDependency `sky-build-setup` is resolved using a github url, where yarn doesn't have a way of knowing if there is a new version of the dependency nor how to update it. The dependencies not belonging to npm (i.e. the ones resolved via urls or `file:`) are marked as `exotic` in the `interactive-upgrade` process.

On the other hand, the dependency `sky-window` comes from npm and yarn can assess if you are using the latest version and eventually update it for you.